# Unable to delegate Replicating Directory Changes to a user in AD - option missing from wizard

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2010, delegation

Disclaimer: I originally asked this over at SharePoint SE, but I figured I'd ask it here too as it's more of an AD problem than a SP specific one.

I'm trying to delegate the Replicating Directory Changes permission to a user using the wizard in AD (following [Spencer Harbar's UPS guide](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)) but for some reason the option doesn't appear in the list of permissions, along with many others that I'm used to seeing. Additionally, when I try to set permissions for the same user on the configuration partition using ADSIEdit, all the permission options are disabled, despite being an Admin.

This is a fresh install of 2008R2 and SP2010, so I'm stumped (as is our resident sysadmin, who set the system up) - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I can't actually read properly and have been clicking on the wrong thing in AD Users & Computers. I'll close the question off...